# Connecting from the sales_flat_order table to the sales_flat_order_item table and merging data (sql

Tags: sql, magento

I'm pulling the order list with SQL. From this table, I connect to the sales_flat_order_item table and pull the products in it. But more records are listed in 1 order. Idont want this.

My SQL Code:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(SFA.created_at),
SFA.increment_id AS "SIPNO",
CONCAT(SUBSTR(SFA.increment_id, 4, 7), REPLACE(RIGHT(SFA.created_at, 4), ':', '')) AS MOK,
SFOI.sku AS UrunKod,
SFA.shipping_description AS KARGO,
CONVERT_TZ(SFA.created_at, '+00:00','+03:00') AS "SIPTARIH"

FROM sales_flat_order SFA 

INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item SFOI ON SFA.entity_id = SFOI.order_id

WHERE SFA.`status` = 'complete' 
AND SFA.increment_id = '400241866'
AND YEAR(SFA.created_at) >= 2022
```

Output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSrmF.png)

I want

| YEAR | SIPNO | MOK | UrunKod | KARGO | SIPTARIH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 400241866 | 241866440 | 1xDK-AC-MPAD03, 1xDK-CB-USB2MICROL300 | Yurtiçi Kargo | 2022-06-16 20:44:40 |

I want to combine purchased products with commas and show them in one field.

How can we write the SQL code?

Comment: You can use XML PATH or STUFF function for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STUFF function in your SELECT query for it.

```
UrunKod = STUFF((
            SELECT ';' + CAST(SFOI.sku AS VARCHAR(999))
            FROM
                sales_flat_order_item SFOI
            WHERE
                SFA.entity_id = SFOI.order_id
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, N''),
```

You can get more information about [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/)

Hope it solves your problem.